# Find and replace next and next and not find the first and last

Tags: regex, textwrangler

Really elementary question but I can't get this to work. My sample text is provided in the bottom of the page.

The only row I want left is the ones looking like this: "178-207    30  WVRTRWALLLLFWLGWLGMLAGAVVIIVRA  -3,95". I currently use TextWrangler on OSX (terminal and me are not friends) which provide regex replacements.
I am trying to do this in steps, and my first step is trying to get rid of all the protein sequences.

In TextWrangler, I search for this:

> Working sequence([^;]*)------------------------------------------------------------

and replace with nothing. However, what I end up with is almost an empty document, as TextWrangler seems to find the first instance of "Working sequence", but the LAST instance of "------------------------------------------------------------". How do I change so this is a step-wise process, finding the first instances of both and replacing with nothing, then the second instance etc?

Thanks and greetings from Sweden

> Results summary for protein: sp|P08195|4F2_HUMAN 4F2 GN=SLC3A2 PE=1 SV=3
>      Translocon TM Analysis Results
>      Partitioning: water to bilayer
>      Window range: 19-30
>
> Number of translocon TM predicted segments: 2
>
> 178-207    30  WVRTRWALLLLFWLGWLGMLAGAVVIIVRA  -3,95
>
> 438-460    23  ARLLTSFLPAQLLRLYQLMLFTL 1,63
>
> Working sequence   length = 630):
>
> MELQPPEASIAVVSIPRQLPGShSEAGVQGLSAGDDSELGShCVAQTGLELLASGDPLPS
>      ASQNAEMIETGSDCVTQAGLQLLASSDPPALASKNAEVTGTMSQDTEVDMKEVELNELEP
>      EKQPMNAASGAAMSLAGAEKNGLVKIKVAEDEAEAAAAAKFTGLSKEELLKVAGSPGWVR
>      TRWALLLLFWLGWLGMLAGAVVIIVRAPRCRELPAQKWWhTGALYRIGDLQAFQGhGAGN
>      LAGLKGRLDYLSSLKVKGLVLGPIhKNQKDDVAQTDLLQIDPNFGSKEDFDSLLQSAKKK
>      SIRVILDLTPNYRGENSWFSTQVDTVATKVKDALEFWLQAGVDGFQVRDIENLKDASSFL
>      AEWQNITKGFSEDRLLIAGTNSSDLQQILSLLESNKDLLLTSSYLSDSGSTGEhTKSLVT
>      QYLNATGNRWCSWSLSQARLLTSFLPAQLLRLYQLMLFTLPGTPVFSYGDEIGLDAAALP
>      GQPMEAPVMLWDESSFPDIPGAVSANMTVKGQSEDPGSLLSLFRRLSDQRSKERSLLhGD
>      FhAFSAGPGLFSYIRhWDQNERFLVVLNFGDVGLSAGLQASDLPASASLPAKADLLLSTQ
>      PGREEGSPLELERLKLEPhEGLLLRFPYAA
>
> ---
>
> Results summary for protein: sp|Q9NPC4|A4GAT_HUMAN OS=Homo sapiens GN=A4GALT PE=2 SV=1
>      Translocon TM Analysis Results
>      Partitioning: water to bilayer
>      Window range: 19-30
>
> Number of translocon TM predicted segments: 1
>
> 19-43  25  RVCTLFIIGFKFTFFVSIMIYWhVV   -1,04
>
> Working sequence   length = 353):
>
> MSKPPDLLLRLLRGAPRQRVCTLFIIGFKFTFFVSIMIYWhVVGEPKEKGQLYNLPAEIP
>      CPTLTPPTPPShGPTPGNIFFLETSDRTNPNFLFMCSVESAARThPEShVLVLMKGLPGG
>      NASLPRhLGISLLSCFPNVQMLPLDLRELFRDTPLADWYAAVQGRWEPYLLPVLSDASRI
>      ALMWKFGGIYLDTDFIVLKNLRNLTNVLGTQSRYVLNGAFLAFERRhEFMALCMRDFVDh
>      YNGWIWGhQGPQLLTRVFKKWCSIRSLAESRACRGVTTLPPEAFYPIPWQDWKKYFEDIN
>      PEELPRLLSATYAVhVWNKKSQGTRFEATSRALLAQLhARYCPTThEAMKMYL
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it to look for "Working sequence" and than anything that's not ';' the first (and next and next...) line of '-' characters aren't -. That's why it's matching everything. It does match the final line of '-' characters because you told it there should be one at the end. I think this will work for you

```
Working sequence([^-]*)------------------------------------------------------------
```